# ZSH - How can I create a function that asks multiple questions leading to a different end result each way? Like a choose your own adventure story

Tags: case, zsh

First, I do apologize as I'm sure this has been asked. But I've been searching for hours and gotten nowhere.
I'm working on my first real function and ZSH or Bash even is what I know best. I'm trying to create a simple function that will ask a series of questions, placing the answers in a variable, and merging them all together to create an end result to simply save time and reduce the amount of typing I've been doing lately.
This is for the recently launched game Fallout 76. I want to create an interactive inventory file where if I type fo76 addweapon, it will ask me questions about this weapon and print the results for fast copy-paste into a trading community.

I've tried many different variations that I've found and what I have now gets me closest, but it's not working. Assume the mode variables have been set prior. What am I doing wrong? And what would be my next step into the next question, which will include a list of effects allowing me to select them based on the number I chose in the previous answer?

```
if [[ $mode="$MODE_ADD_WEAPON" ]]; then
        title="Add Weapon"
        prompt="How many stars does this weapon have?"
        options1=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "Quit")
        PS3="$prompt "
        select opt in "{$options1[@]}"; do
            if [[ -z $opt ]]; then
                echo "$REPLY is not a valid option, try again"
                REPLY=
                    elif [[ $REPLY="$1" ]]; then
                        RESULT="$REPLY Star ";
            fi

        while true; do
            STARS="$RESULT"; echo "$STARS"
        done
        prompt="What prefix does this $STARS weapon have?"
        options2=("Anti-armor" "Assassin's" "Berserker's" "Bloodied" "Exterminator's" "Furious" "Ghoul Slayer's" "Hunter's" "Instigating" "Junkie's" "Mutant's" "Mutant Slayer's" "Nocturnal" "Stalker's" "Suppressor's" "Troubleshooter's" "Vampire's" "Zealot's")
        PS3="$prompt "
        select opt in "{options2[@]}"; do
            if [[ -z $opt ]]; then
                echo "$REPLY is not a valid option, try again"
                REPLY=
                    elif [[ $REPLY=$REPLY ]]; then
                        echo $REPLY; RESULT="$STARS $REPLY"
                    fi
                done
            while true; do
                PREFIX="$REPLY"; echo "$STARS $PREFIX"
            done
        done
fi
}
```

My current plan was to apply each result to it's own variable and echo them at the end looking like [3 Star] [Instigating Bloody +Strength] [Deathclaw Gauntlet] priced at [500]. Something along those lines.

Comment: Do you have to do this in bash? It would be significantly easier to do this in other programming languages

Comment: I imagine it would be, unfortunately this is the one I know remotely well enough to create a function in. There's also other parts that I haven't worked on yet, but I think those will be easier. I have made a bit of progress with simplifying the code. My problem though has been it loops. No matter my input it will ask the same question. I finally got an input to print the result, but it prints it continuously and I don't know how to stop and move to the next question.

Comment: Bash is quite difficult compared to other languages. With what you know of bash, you could quite quickly pick up another language such as python or javascript(nodejs) and start writing scripts like these. I would highly recommend it

Comment: For some reason, Bash has always clicked with me. Maybe from the days I've spent just studying manuals. I never had to use these commands though, so they're rather tricky. I've been studying HTML and javascript. But moreso the fundamentals rather than anything specific. That's pretty encouraging though, so I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @SwampStorage: **1.** When posting code, please indent it properly; otherwise it will be hard to read. For instance, the intendation of your `elif` does not match the `if`.  **2.** I don't see the `done` belonging to the first `select`. As posted, the program seems therefore to be syntactically incorrect. **3.** What is the purpose of the two infinite `while` loops? **4.** Note that `select` by its nature already is a loop, but you never leave this loop. From the zsh man-page about `select`: _The list is executed after each selection until a break command is executed._

Answer (score 0):

With the loops, you need an exit condition. Current your condition is "true" which mean it will always loop forever. Generally you create a loop with some kind of expression that is expected to change within the loop. You can also use "break" to exit a loop

Here is an example from http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html

```
#!/bin/bash

# Calculate the average of a series of numbers.

SCORE="0"
AVERAGE="0"
SUM="0"
NUM="0"

while true; do

  echo -n "Enter your score [0-100%] ('q' for quit): "; read SCORE;

  if (("$SCORE" < "0"))  || (("$SCORE" > "100")); then
    echo "Be serious.  Common, try again: "
  elif [ "$SCORE" == "q" ]; then
    echo "Average rating: $AVERAGE%."
    break
  else
    SUM=$[$SUM + $SCORE]
    NUM=$[$NUM + 1]
    AVERAGE=$[$SUM / $NUM]
  fi

done

echo "Exiting."
```

Comment: Okay. I haven't pieced together exactly how I can apply that, but I'll take it as a challenge and mess with it a bit. Thank you I appreciate the feedback, I didn't know where to start looking. EDIT: That didn't take long, I caught on, thanks.